# How to filter on panda dataframe for missing values?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, filter

I have a data frame with mutliple columns and some of these have missing values.

I would to filter so that I can return a dataframe that has missing values on one or two specific columns.

Can anyone help me figure out how to do that?

Comment: See pandas' page on [Indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Having a dataframe "df" with a columns "A"

```
df_missing = df[df['A'].isnull()]
```